# Si la variable get está definida el scroll se posicione en un sitio específico

Tags: php, jquery

He encontrado códigos para que el scroll se posicione en un sitio específico pero cuando le das a un botón... pero no se como hacerlo para que solo lo haga cuando la variable $_GET["nombre"] esté definida

```
<h3 id="cat"> Aquí quiero que se posicione el scroll</h3>
```

Pero que solo lo haga si la variable $_GET["nombre] esté definida, pero solo encuentor ejemplos para que sea al darle a algún botón, o si en la barra de direcciones añado un #nombre

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta. Deberías poner el código con el que estás trabajando, puedes hacerlo pulsando en [edit].

Comment: Hola, `$_GET["nombre]` estará definida en el lado del servidor, y desde ahí no tienes acceso al lado del cliente (`JavaScript`). Esta variable está definida en el servidor cuando en la `URL` está presente algún parámetro `search` con ese nombre. Por lo tanto, solo deberías desde `JavaScript` verificar los parámetros de búsqueda de la `URL` y dependiendo de los mismos hacer scroll hacia el elemento que desees (como te ha dicho el compañero @A.Cedano, no se entiende si deseas hacerlo siempre hacia el mismo elemento o hacia elementos dinámicos)